# Хотел написать код который проверяет, есть ли конкретная буква в строке. Но не работает

Tags: python

```
string=input("Строка::")
letter=input("Буква::")
for i in string:
    if letter in soz:
        print("YEs")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Comment: Код исправил, но на будущее - приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь. Исправил заголовок для ясности.

Comment: Откуда взялась переменная `soz`?

Comment: ``soz`` это что и откуда взялось?

Answer (score 0):

Исправлен код - цикл был не нужен + тернарный оператор тут красивее использовать.

```
string=input("Строка::")
letter=input("Буква::")
print("Yes" if letter in string else "No")
```

Comment: если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: можно вообще ``print(letter in string)``. Будет, правда, не йес/ноу печатать, но какая разница :)

Comment: а если нужно yes/nо, то ``print({True: "Yes", False: "No"}[letter in string])``